# Group by Aggregate Case statement and display case column and count

Tags: sql, group-by, count, case

I have a query that i need to modify to display all the values in the Bucket field and show there count and METRIC_VALUE

```sql
select 
CASE
WHEN sum(e.Metric_Value) >1000 THEN '>1000'
WHEN sum(e.Metric_Value) >500  THEN '>500'
WHEN sum(e.Metric_Value) >100  THEN '>100'
WHEN sum(e.Metric_Value) >1 THEN '>1'
ELSE '<1' END AS "Bucket",
count(distinct i.INTEGRATORKEY) as Count,
SUM(e.Metric_Value) AS Metric_Value  
from "ANALYTICS_PROD"."ACCOUNT_SCORE"."AGG_AS_ENVELOPES" e
left join   "ANALYTICS_PROD"."BODM"."INTEGRATORLOOKUPVIEW"  i
ON e.KeyId = i.KeyId 
AND e.SourceKey = i.SourceKey
```

The result of the above  query only displays first row for '>1000'
However I need to see a bucket of other Metric Value like
>1000, >500, >100, >1

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  You have an aggregation query with no `group by`.  That is quite suspicious.

Comment: Agreed upon what Gordon said + why you need left join here?

Comment: As Gordon has mentioned you have no `Group BY` so you will only get one result and we can assume that the SUM of the metric_value for your single result is greater than 1000.  You need to define your grouping level to get it to return more than one result.

Answer (score 0):

By applying aggregation functions (`SUM`, `COUNT`) and not having a `GROUP BY` clause you aggregate all rows to one result row. Obviously the total of all `Metric_Value` in the table is greater than 1000.

What you seem to want instead is a count per bucket, so group by bucket:

```
select 
  case
    when e.metric_value > 1000 then '>1000'
    when e.metric_value >  500 then '>500'
    when e.metric_value >  100 then '>100'
    when e.metric_value >    1 then '>1'
    else                            '<=1'
  end as bucket,
  count(distinct i.integratorkey) as count_of_integrators,
  sum(e.metric_value) as sum_of_metric_values
from analytics_prod.account_score.agg_as_envelopes e
left join analytics_prod.bodm.integratorlookupview  i on e.keyid = i.keyid 
                                                     and e.sourcekey = i.sourcekey
group by
  case
    when e.metric_value > 1000 then '>1000'
    when e.metric_value >  500 then '>500'
    when e.metric_value >  100 then '>100'
    when e.metric_value >    1 then '>1'
    else                            '<=1'
  end;
```